# A category of jokes based exclusively on puns and wordplay?

Tags: выражения, стилистика

In English, there are "classic" [knock-knock jokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knock-knock_joke) (1) based on puns, and two-line question-answer jokes (2) with witty punchlines:

1.

> xxx: Knock knock!
>
> yyy: Who's there?
>
> xxx: Lego!
>
> yyy: Lego who?
>
> xxx: Lego to the movies!

2.

> Q: Where do astronauts hang out?
>
> A: Spacebar.

There are more varieties, of course, but I'm only interested in these two, as they both are concise and don't require a setting or a backstory.

**Question:** Are there similar jokes in the Russian language that are short, based exclusively on puns and wordplay, and that are currently popular? Some examples would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a question about language, it's too broad and by definition can not have one answer.

Comment: @shabunc The question certainly _is_ about Russian language, and it certainly _can_ have one answer ("Is there a similar phenomenon?" "Yes, there is".)

Comment: @mustaccio is this there's similar phenomenon in Russia is too broad. Imagine question about say prison slang - is there's such thing like prison slang in Russia?

Comment: I thought my question was very specific, and not at all broad: Are there similar jokes in the Russian language that are based exclusively on puns and wordplay and if there are, some examples would be great. The question is about stylistics, @shabunc

Comment: I still believe it is off-topic, the other thing is that anyone can vote for reopening it.

Comment: @shabunc You seem to be the only one who finds the question off-topic. Here's my vote to re-open it.

Comment: @H.Zeta - replaced your updated question with the one you have posted in comments, as it more narrow and clear. Hope this will help to reopen your post.

Comment: @Artemix and Mikhail, thanks for support guys. Was surprised to find here that a question about language stylistics can be labeled "off-topic" in a language community.

Comment: Oh good, now that the question has been revised, my answer does not make any sense.

Comment: This question reminds me of one of the scenes in the beginning of Borat.

Comment: I think many Stierlitz jokes fall under that type.

Comment: Why someone tries closing it and downvotes? I don't see a problem here. Where else are you supposed to make a question about culture and language? Forums are bad idea and work badly nowadays, you need to register, invent a password, etc, and deal with people expressing themselves but giving little value. Here instead are people willing to help. It's broad, yet it's not a discussive question like "post your jokes here". I don't see why this SE section should limit itself to grammar peculiarities (given that all word questions are directed to dictionaries).

Comment: BTW, the reason SO/SE appeared was that forums degraded and gave poor answers with a lot of useless opinionated discussion. I think the answers here maintain the intent of SO/SE, of giving value and refraining from empty discussions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not quite sure but the following jokes should correspond to the "question -answer "type.

> – Ты высыпаешься по ночам?
> – Куда высыпаюсь?
>
> – Сколько бы вы дали мне лет?
> – Вам своих мало?
>
> – До меня не доходят смс!
> – Спокойно, прочтите еще раз.
>
> – Этот поезд куда следует?
> – Куда следует.
>
> – Это курица?
> – Нет, кушается.

Comment: спасибо поржал!

Comment: I would like to mention another type: a statement (or rather an action ) – a comment.  Почтальон Печкин разнес почту. Здание восстановлению не подлежит.

Comment: Of course, Schtirlitz jokes come to mind :)

Answer (score 6):

I doubt there is such thing, but here you can find the list of the most popular anecdote topics:

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Анекдот#Распространённые темы русских анекдотов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.91.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D1.85_.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, повеселилась.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on this site. Could you please cite the relevant part of the linked resource in your post? Thanks!

Comment: A bit too general I'd say, as in this article on British homour: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_humor Would like to see something more to the point.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow popular is the genre of пирожки, poems in [iamb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)) but without rhyme. Appeared in 2003 in the internets.

These are several random (not interconnected) examples of pirozhki:

```
олег на утреннике в школе
глядит на пляшущих детей
и понимает что для счастья
порой достаточно кота

вчера я продал душу черту
причем по выгодной цене
но он заметил в ней дефекты
и по гарантии вернул

я сзади подойду прикрою
ладонями твои глаза
и буду слушать грустно виктор
иван василий константин 

когда мы встретились глазами
мы оба поняли что нам
необходимо повстречаться
друг с другом чем нибудь ещё
```

([source](http://www.adme.ru/svoboda-narodnoe-tvorchestvo/luchshie-pirozhki-i-poroshki-2014-722360/))

```
"а где тут руль?" — спросил гагарин
"деревня!" — буркнул королёв
"ещё спроси «а где тут вожжи»"
"ещё «поехали» скажи"
```

(punctuation is mine)

Comment: Pirozhki are cool, but have absolutely nothing to do with knock-knock jokes.

Comment: The initial question title was about classical types of jokes, so pirozhki fit that question well. Now I see it's a bit different.

Comment: @culebrón, I find your input very interesting and useful nonetheless. Please be so kind and don't delete it. I haven't yet had time to sit and ponder on the answers, and some of them are already missing. Moderators's been acting a bit uncooperative and counterproductive.

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs as I see the question now, pirozhki are what is asked about. There's lot of wordplay in them. Might be not as popular as Shtirlitz jokes, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @culebrón Well, the question was about a particular type of joke. There is a lot of humor and wordplay in many different forms of poetry, including pirozhki, poroshki, and limericks, to use an English-language example. Do you really think they correspond to knock-knock jokes?

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs the question wasn't to give an exact cognate to the door joke. *"short, based exclusively on puns and wordplay, and that are currently popular"* Pirozhki and limericks match this definition too.

Comment: @culebrón okay, whatever.

Comment: Indeed, epigrammatic poetry is a big deal in the Russian literature, but not sure if it could be called "popular today"

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing similar to knock-knock jokes in Russian (fortunately, I would say). There are plenty of jokes involving puns, and based exclusively on puns and wordplay, but not in a recognizable form with a rigid structure like that.

Comment: Are there any tendencies or patterns within the entirety of that pun/wordplay category? Do they gravitate more towards aphorisms/storytelling, or are they more like improvised/staged dialogues?

Comment: I would say dialogues. There are some nice examples in V.V.'s answer, and they are all dialogues. There are also some jokes about people from Georgia and Armenia who don't understand some intricacies of the Russian language and make funny mistakes. These jokes can be obscene or innocent, stupid or smart, but there's often a pun.

Comment: P.S. but dialogues within a story, not the astronauts hanging out at the  spacebar kind. I thought of a few not involving any dialogue at all, just a pun in a story. Besides the ethnic jokes, there are quite a few with recurring characters, that's where you will often hear a pun.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about popularity, but I personally find those funny:

> xxx: - У нее иссяк запал.
>   yyy: - Что запало?
>   xxx: - Иссяк.

and

> Q: Кулич будешь?
>
> A: Я бросил. Мне бы выпечь.

Tell me if you need explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Joke based on wordplay: maybe, "прибаутка" ([see here](http://www.vedu.ru/expdic/26094/))